# Избавиться от повторного вывода поля MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Создал БД, создал запрос, все корректно за исключением вывода. На сайте спросил почему так, ответили что MySQL неправильно обрабатывает USING.
Как избавиться от повторного поля. Неужели нереально?
Делал так:

```
SELECT * FROM owners JOIN pets
USING (owner_id);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо это действительно сложно

Comment: Вы указали Select *, поэтому mysql вывел вам все поля и owners.owner_id и pets.owner_id, которые Вы воспринимаете как дублирующиеся. Пока могу только предложить явно указать поля, которые Вам нужны

Comment: mysql нормально обрабатывает using. Так, как то и должно быть. В чём вы видите "повторный вывод поля" и почему данных в ваших таблицах не указано в вопросе?

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin, да Вы правы. Ведь * выводит все поля в данном случае обоих таблиц. И все же только явно указать? А какой бы owner_id выводили Вы из таблици owners или pets раз они связані, то єто одно и тоже, но что правильнее (корректнее) писать в запросе?

Comment: @Мелкий, извините, что не написал данные (очень туплю, видимо, устал), но они правильно выведены в таблице, за исключением что ли оформления так как последний столбец налез на перед

Comment: @Muscled Boy, с mysql так близко не знаком, что бы сказать можно ли убрать такое дублирование, поэтому не стал оформлять ответ, вдруг не прав. По поводу owner_id, я вообще обычно в основной таблице просто id называю, а в связанной {имя_основной_таблицы}_id, и тогда не будет такой путаницы.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, не помгло

Comment: @MuscledBoy, так вопрос в том, что клиенту mysql не хватило ширины терминала для вывода таблицы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в запросе вместо JOIN написать LEFT JOIN тогда дубликатов не будет

**Дополнение**

Если не поможет, тогда вот такой запрос

```
SELECT o.*, p.name, p.breed from owners o INNER JOIN pets p USING(owner_id);
```

Это так называемые алиасы, одно из их назначений, чтобы не писать имя таблицы целиком. Соответственно "o" – это алиас для owners, а "p" – алиас для pets. Ваш последний комментарий верен.

Comment: напишите Ваш ответ полностью пожалуйста

Comment: Ві знаете помогло, а не могли бы Вы объяснить что такое o , p я только начинающий и мне не все понятно. Я так понимаю, єто сокращения таблиц или что?

Comment: Выходит мы выводим все поля таблици owners и имя и породу pets?

Comment: а если бы было несколько таблиц, начинающихся, с о, каким тогда будет алиас? и вообще как понять, каким будет алиас?

Comment: @MuscledBoy alias вы придумываете сами, важно чтобы он не совпадал с зарезервированными словами

Comment: @Jean-Claude,  спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Пробуй так

```
SELECT owners.* FROM owners JOIN pets USING( owner_id)
```

Comment: если к параметрам owners.* добавить pets.pet_id, pets.name, pets.breed , то получим нужное